# What is the practicality of placing non-formatting elements inside javadoc?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

So, i've been using javadoc for quite a while and know that it supports basic text formatting like `<strong> <em> <ul> <ol> etc..`

Today i was doing some javadoc, and i wanted to put in `<input/>` and `<select/>` so i wrapped it in a `{@literal ..}`

But i noticed that javadoc wasn't complaining when i put those in without it wrapped in `@literal`.

To my surprise, i looked at the method signature and read the javadoc, and it actually PARSED the fields.

[image]

**So my question is, is there a practical use for putting html elements like `input` and `select`?** And furthermore, isn't this a security concern if somebody generated a web-based javadoc from eclipse?

Comment: generate nice javadoc (see [GWT widgets javadoc](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/) for example)

Comment: let me be clear - i'm curious about the input, and select fields in particular.  obviously the rest of the html elements are self explanitory.

Comment: You might want to put a contact form inside your javadoc.. (just thinking..:)

Comment: edited the title as it was VERY misleading... (hopefully ridding of my downvote)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for allowing HTML is to support basic formatting (font styles, lists, tables, etc).  I cannot think of a reason that you would want form controls in there. Likely, preventing such usage wasn't deemed important enough to spend development cycles.

Comment: thanks for the answer Konstantin, and I apologize for the confusion - i edited my title to make things clearer. I understand the use of lists, styles, tables, etc. but input's, and selects, and possibly others like `<script>` even.

Comment: I suspect that it isn't about practicality of these constructs within javadoc, but rather the cost of precluding their usage weighed against the potential harm.